Do the Enterprisians from Star Trek: Prodigy reference a specific episode of The Original Series?
Series 1, episode 13: All the World's a Stage.
The crew encounter a culture (the Enterprisians) that seems to be based on an encounter with the crew and characters from TOS.; Sulu, Kirk, Spock are referenced in the names of these people, the home-made uniforms echo those of TOS., their mannerisms and sayings are familiar: "Live logs, and proper", their Shakespearean-style rendition of the "logs" - in a form reminiscent of an episode of Voyager featuring B'Elanna Torres masquerading as a local legend and Muse.

Found blog.trekcore.com 4/7/24.  Copyright (possibly) Paramount. Fair usage.
There are various references: A specie from Galaxy Quest, Star Trek Voyager, TOS., etc..
Is there a specific episode where the encounter that might have lead to all this is portrayed or mentioned in the original series, Star Trek or any feature film with that crew?

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_the_World%27s_a_Stage_(episode)

Not an episode per se, but in "A Piece of the Action" a 'gangster planet' had been created because someone left a book on Chicago gangs of the 1920's with the imitative inhabitants of Sigma Iotia II. Anyway, for a time there was this idea among the Deep Space Nine writers that the characters would visit Sigma Iotia II and find it had become a 'Planet of the Trekkies'. The idea was later used for a TNG comic "A Piece of Reaction".
So to answer your question, unless the planet in this STP episode is called Sigma Iotia II, it appears the Enterprisians had an 'off-screen' encounter with Kirk & Co.
